# Any correct procedure for couchbase backup and restore?

Tags: backup, restore, couchbase

I have just started using couchbase server and trying to configure backup and restore method. We require to take backup for each couchbase node or cluster backup also available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recommendations from the professional services team at Couchbase:

- Use cbbackupmgr to take differential backups (according to your recover point objectives).
- Merge backups to the number of restore points that you want.
- Compact the backup set after each backup operation

Some references for you:

- [cbbackupmgr tutorial](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-tutorial.html)
- [cbbackupmgr strategies](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-strategies.html)

Comment: Can you give me specific command? I have 4 buckets in my couchbase cluster so need to take one by one or one go?

Comment: There isn't just one specific command. Definitely check out the cbbackupmgr tutorial; it will take you through the process step by step. Is there something specific you're having trouble with from that tutorial?

Comment: I am following this procedure https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/cli/backup-cbbackup.html . however procedure is working but I have one doubt that we require to perform this step on above link "Filter keys during backup" while taking couchbase backup"Back up single node, all buckets" . please suggest.